# Custom Label value not working in SOQL Query

Tags: salesforce, soql

I am trying to use custom label value in SOQL Query. Query is not accepting custom label value. it is expecting number.

Integer num_days = Integer.valueOf(System.Label.Num_of_Days);
Select id, name FROM contact WHERE LastModifiedDate >= LAST_N_DAYS :num_days

Thanks,
Anil Kumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full syntax of the "constant" you're using already has a semicolon in it: `LAST_N_DAYS:7` etc. The whole thing has to be a text known at compile time, not just the part before `:`

This won't even compile, with 1 or 2 semicolons.

```
Integer x = 7;
List<Account> accs = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:x];
System.debug(accs);
```

You'll need to use dynamic SOQL or use your custom label to construct a date variable

```
String x = '7';
List<Account> accs = Database.query('SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:' + x);
System.debug(accs);

DateTime cutoff = System.today().addDays(- Integer.valueOf(x));
System.debug(cutoff);
System.debug([SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE CreatedDate <= TODAY AND CreatedDate >= :cutoff]);
```